# Android Progressbar when consuming WCF

Tags: android, multithreading, wcf, progress-bar

I have written progress bar when I consume WCF part. I have to know after get response it need to dismiss.

```
   ProgressThread progThread;
   ProgressDialog progDialog;
   int typeBar;                     // Determines type progress bar: 0 = spinner, 1 = horizontal
   int delay = 40;                  // manually define thedelay
   int maxBarValue = 200;           // manually define the maximum value 

   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        typeBar = 0;
        showDialog(typeBar);
        return true;
    case 1:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // Spinner
    progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
    progThread.start();
    return progDialog;

}

 final Handler handler = new Handler() {
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

         int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
         progDialog.setProgress(total);
         if (total <= 0){
             dismissDialog(typeBar);
             progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
         }
     }
 };
```

This is thread class

```
   private class ProgressThread extends Thread {    
    final static int DONE = 0;
    final static int RUNNING = 1;
    Handler mHandler;
    int mState;
    int total;

    ProgressThread(Handler h) {
        mHandler = h;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mState = RUNNING;   
        total = maxBarValue;
        while (mState == RUNNING) {
            try {
                loadDownloadData();
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Thread was Interrupted");
            }

            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", total);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            total--;   
        }
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
    }
}
```

WCF call method is **loadDownloadData();** , Where want to call & how we can define the time frame for sleep, after getting response only it need to dismis this progress bar...

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly should your method do?

At the moment it looks like you are calling some method in loop and after that you sleep a thread. If your `loadDownloadData` calls the WCF it will be called in each cycle? If it doesn't start asynchronous processing it will wait until the method completes and only after that it will continue to sleeping the thread.

If you want to have progress bar for downloading content over WCF you cannot use such approach. First the whole WCF call must run asynchronously. Next you need to know amount of downloaded data upfront and you need to read data continuously - only that will allow you to control real progress bar. Normal HTTP processing will write all data to the server, pass them to the network, load all data to the buffer on the client and after that your method return the result - from client API such operation is atomic (= you cannot measure progress). This is usually avoided by chunked data where server pushes data in chunks and client is able to read these chunks like a stream. In WCF it is performed by streaming transfer mode.

At the moment you should simply use some unlimited spinner and wait for operation to complete.

Comment: Actually I am doing Synchronizing sq-lite & SQL server. In that situation I want to download chunks of data from WCF to Android, It happens in backend client need to show progress bar for waiting until that process finish. From your suggestion I should have Synchronize loadDownloadData() mtd. I am really don't understand  If i use  Synchronization , Mutiple user access. those users need to wait? or is it spread thread for each users? pls help me.

Comment: This is not about multiple users. You have single android application used by single user who want to download some data and see a progress bar. If `loadDownloadData` is blocking then your thread sleep doesn't make sense.